# UINavigationController Not pushing the viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm creating a table view application.
I have to display a web view when a cell in the table view is touched.
But the tableView's navigation controller is showing a nil value.
And it is not pushing to the detailsViewController.
Anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

      NewsDetailsViewController *detailsVc=[[NewsDetailsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewsDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

      NSString *launchURL = [nf.newsStories [indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];

      detailsVc.url = launchURL;

      NSLog(@"View controllers before pushing : %@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsVc animated:YES];
      NSLog(@"View controllers after pushing : %@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);
    }
```

[NavigationController Value in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0jZz.png)

Comment: NewsDetailsViewController is present from someview?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with creating your controller which this line

```
NewsDetailsViewController *detailsVc=[[NewsDetailsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewsDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Try to replace it with this one

```
NewsDetailsViewController *detailsVc= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsDetailsViewController"
                                     owner:self
                                   options:nil][0];
```

Anyway I advise you to move to using Storyboards and Segues